# How can I pass this list index 0 in item in "Place" function

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

How can I pass this list item in the javascript function ??

```
    {% for a in ard %}
            <h3 style="font-style:italic; font-family:verdana;">{{a[0]}}</h3><br>
            <li>{{a[1]}}</li>
            <li>{{a[2]}}</li>
            <li>{{a[3]}}</li>
            <button onclick="Place({{a[0]}});">Place order</button>
            <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what is the content of `ard`?

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto It's contains string.

Comment: When you iterate over a string using `for in`, each iteration takes a string character as the current item. Have a look on this short example: https://repl.it/repls/AzureKaleidoscopicUtilities

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto Actually it's has group of rows copied from a table.

Comment: Is your problem only related to the `onclick` action in the `button` tag? I mean, is the list being well rendered on the screen?

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto The list is not rendered on the screen, instead I have the error which shows that "a" is undefined

Comment: Can provide a sample of `ard`, changing the sensitive data to some dummy string? The data structure is important to understand this error

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto It's something like this :  ("Uno R3"   " with USB"   "microroll")

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a node and use `querySelectorAll`?

```
    {% for a in ard %}
            <h3 style="font-style:italic; font-family:verdana;">{{a[0]}}</h3><br>
            <ul class="item-list">
                <li>{{a[1]}}</li>
                <li>{{a[2]}}</li>
                <li>{{a[3]}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button onclick="Place({{a[0]}});">Place order</button>
            <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

`document.querySelectorAll('.item-list > li')`

Comment: several identical id on the page? Are you seriously?

Comment: Glanced over the loop, my bad. Swap out the `id` for a `class`. Not that big a deal.

Comment: @Nathan I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ard` is a tuple of strings, as provided on the from comments `("Uno R3", "with USB", "microroll")`. In order to create a list out of the data structure, you should create each list item tag `<li>` using the for in loop.

Your code on `jinja2` would be similar to the following:

```
{# Title using the first element of the tuple #}
<h3 style="font-style:italic; font-family: verdana;">
  {{ ard[0] }} 
</h3>

<br />

<ul id="arduino-items">
{% for item in ard %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<button onclick="Place( {{ a[0] }} );">Place order</button>
<hr>
```

and the resulting HTML rendered will be like the following:

```html
<h3>Uno R3</h3>
<ul id="arduino-items">
  <li>Uno R3</li>
  <li>with USB</li>
  <li>microroll</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="Place("Uno R3");">Place order</button>
<hr />
```